# jquery Stop Animation on last image

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery and have a simple script that scrolls through three images, the problem is I can not get the animation to stop on the last image.

```
var tt, nn;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#promobox").innerfade({
    animationtype:"fade",
    speed:"slow",
    timeout:1000,
    type:"sequence",
    containerheight:"auto"
  })
});
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery Cycle Plugin, it is based on the InnerFade plugin but has many extra features and options like `autostop` that allows you to stop the slideshow after a certain number of transitions.

- Cycle Plugin : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/
- Cycle Plugin Options : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html